# Windows Server 2016 RDS Users Customised Start Menu disappearing

Tags: group-policy, remote-desktop, windows-server-2016

I have a new RDS Server (Windows Server 2016 with RDSH, RDCB, RDWeb and RD Licensing all on a single server). Everything is working pretty well but I have an issue with the custom Start Menu for a non-admin user group.

I have exported a start menu template XML file, it is in a local folder that all users have read access to, and pointed the Group Policy [User Configuration / Policies / Administrative Templates / Start Menu and Taskbar / Start Layout] to this file. The contents of the file is here:

```
<LayoutModificationTemplate Version="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/LayoutModification">
  <LayoutOptions StartTileGroupCellWidth="6" />
  <DefaultLayoutOverride LayoutCustomizationRestrictionType="OnlySpecifiedGroups">
    <StartLayoutCollection>
      <defaultlayout:StartLayout GroupCellWidth="6" xmlns:defaultlayout="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/FullDefaultLayout">
        <start:Group Name="enTIRE" xmlns:start="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/StartLayout">
          <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="0" Row="0" DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\MyApps\App1.lnk" />
          <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="2" Row="0" DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\MyApps\App2.lnk" />
          <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="4" Row="0" DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\MyApps\App3.lnk" />
        </start:Group>
      </defaultlayout:StartLayout>
    </StartLayoutCollection>
  </DefaultLayoutOverride>
</LayoutModificationTemplate>
```

This is applied to a specific user group, and when creating users it is applying successfuly. I can log in as one of the new user accounts and the Start menu is showing correctly.

Here is my scenario:
 - Admin user connected, above menu is applied in GPO and 3 new user accounts are created (User1, User2, User3)

- Log in as User1. Start menu is correct
- Log out and then in as User1. Start menu is correct
- Log in as User2. Start menu is correct
- Log out all users (Admin, User1, User2)
- Log in as User1. Start menu is blank
- Log in as User2. Start menu is blank
- Log in as User3. Start menu is correct
- Log out and then in as User3. Start menu is blank

I am having a hard time locating the issue and would appreciate any suggestions.

---

Update:

I looked at [Windows Server 2016 Start Menu Options Disabled on Admin Login](https://serverfault.com/questions/838058/windows-server-2016-start-menu-options-disabled-on-admin-login), and looked at the blog posted suggested by Robert Angell, https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askpfeplat/2017/05/08/mysteriously-disappearing-start-menu-tiles-and-roaming-user-profiles/. The KB update listed in the post, KB4013429, does not install and tells me it is not applicable to my system, mostly likely because it has been replace by newer updates, all of which are installed. I did set the registry key mentioned, however it has not helped.

---

Update 2:

This issue appears to be linked to User Profile Disks and what is being saved between sessions. Within the Session Collection properties dialog, under User Profile Disks, if i enable the option to "Store all user settings and data on the user profile disk", the start menus are preserved. Previously I was only storing a selection of items (including the "Roaming user profile data" and "User registry data".

I saw some suggestions to also store the \appdata\local\microsoft\windows folder, but this did not seem to work for me. **For now, having everything stored solves my issue**